# Lodash filter based on three or more inputs

Tags: javascript, lodash

Im trying to construct a filter based on three input selectors. The logic is as follows:

- If only one of the three inputs has been selected the filter should return all results based on only this selector value and NOT the unselected inputs
- If two of the three inputs has been selected the results should be filter based on only these two and NOT the unselected input
- If all of the three inputs has been selected the results should be filtered on all three

My code feels verbose and not scalable (see below). Does anyone have ideas on how to optimise this?

This is what i'm working with so far. `hasSelectedBuildingtype`,`hasSelectedInstrument` and `hasSelectedRegion` checks if the inputs have been selected. Accordingly i'm manually checking the state of all the inputs:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

result = _.filter(this.examples, function(entry) {

    // Single checks (if only bulding or region or instrument selected)

    if (
        hasSelectedBuildingtype &&
        !hasSelectedRegion &&
        !hasSelectedInstrument
    ) {
        if (
            entry.buildingtypes.includes(
                vm.selectedBuildingtype
            )
        ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (
        hasSelectedInstrument &&
        !hasSelectedRegion &&
        !hasSelectedBuildingtype
    ) {
        if (entry.instruments.includes(vm.selectedInstrument)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (
        hasSelectedRegion &&
        !hasSelectedInstrument &&
        !hasSelectedBuildingtype
    ) {
        if (entry.regionid === vm.selectedRegion) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Double checks (if only bulding AND region or instrument AND etc selected)

    if (
        hasSelectedRegion &&
        hasSelectedBuildingtype &&
        !hasSelectedInstrument
    ) {
        if (
            entry.regionid === vm.selectedRegion &&
            entry.buildingtypes.includes(
                vm.selectedBuildingtype
            )
        ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (
        hasSelectedInstrument &&
        hasSelectedBuildingtype &&
        !hasSelectedRegion
    ) {
        if (
            entry.instruments.includes(vm.selectedInstrument) &&
            entry.buildingtypes.includes(
                vm.selectedBuildingtype
            )
        ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (
        hasSelectedInstrument &&
        hasSelectedRegion &&
        !hasSelectedBuildingtype
    ) {
        if (
            entry.instruments.includes(vm.selectedInstrument) &&
            entry.regionid === vm.selectedRegion
        ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Triple check (if all types selected)

    if (
        hasSelectedInstrument &&
        hasSelectedRegion &&
        hasSelectedBuildingtype
    ) {
        if (
            entry.instruments.includes(vm.selectedInstrument) &&
            entry.regionid === vm.selectedRegion &&
            entry.buildingtypes.includes(
                vm.selectedBuildingtype
            )
        ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Create an array of functions e.g. `if(hasSelectedBuildingtype) funs.push(() => entry.instruments.includes(vm.selectedInstrument);` and then `return _.every(funcs, fn => fn())`.

Comment: Thanks for the input @GruffBunny! I'll give that a go!

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is to use bit alias per boolean flag. You'll need a contract stating the position of each flag in one integer. So suppose the

```
bit 0: hasSelectedBuildingtype
bit 1: hasSelectedRegion
bit 2: hasSelectedInstrument
...
```

then your initial assignments would be done this way;

```
let myInputFlags = hasSelectedBuildingtype << 0 |
                   hasSelectedRegion << 1 |
                   hasSelectedInstrument << 2 |
                   // ... << 3, << 4, etc
```

and then your comparisons become as simple as comparing to one integer, e.g.

```
/**
 * Checking that hasSelectedBuildingtype === false
 *           and hasSelectedRegion === false
 *           and hasSelectedInstrument === true
 */
if (myInputFlags === 4) {
  ...
```

You can further create alias for comparison numbers like;

```
let hasSelected = {
  ...,
  INSTRUMENT_ONLY: 4,
  ...
};
```

so that your branches become a lot more expressive. E.g.

```
if (myInputFlags === hasSelected.INSTRUMENT_ONLY) {
  ...
```

This way, if you want to add additional boolean checks in the future, all you'll need to maintain is the values and add an extra bit-wise OR to the formula.

Comment: Hi! Uh interesting solution. I'll give it a spin!